# Why does Thunderbird cause an error when launching Firefox, if it's already running?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

I have Thunderbird (v52.9.1) setup to launch Firefox on http(s) links.

Specifically, it's setup to run a script that contains (besides the shebang):

```sh
firefox --profile /path/to/profile --private-window "$@"
```

The problem is that if Firefox is already running, and I open an http(s) link in Thunderbird, I get the error:

```
Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.
```

What puzzles me is that if I execute the same script via terminal, or desktop environment, Firefox is opened without any issue (even if there is another one running).

Why does this happen?

Comment: My firefox command does not provide those options `--profile` and `--private-window`, only `-P` and `-private`. Anyway, does yours have `-no-remote`? It might help.

Comment: @Quasímodo thanks for the reply! I've tried to add it, but it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Try to open Firefox profile icon used to start Firefox with a text editor, look in it for -no-remote and delete that (only the "-no-remote")

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird sets a lot of environment variables ([this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=876412) may be related), which will change Firefox behavior. It's not clear if this is intended or not.

The solution is to find an unset them all; the list I've found in my case, with related `unset`s, is:

```sh
unset MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER
unset MOZ_ASSUME_USER_NS
unset MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DATA_DIRECTORY
unset MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_EVENTS_DIRECTORY
unset MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_RESTART_ARG_0
unset MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_RESTART_ARG_1
unset MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_RESTART_ARG_2
unset MOZ_LAUNCHED_CHILD
unset MOZ_NEW_INSTANCE
unset NO_AT_BRIDGE
unset NO_EM_RESTART
unset XRE_BINARY_PATH
unset XRE_PROFILE_LOCAL_PATH
unset XRE_PROFILE_NAME
unset XRE_PROFILE_PATH
unset XRE_START_OFFLINE
unset XUL_APP_FILE
```